# LVM pv lost, testdisk says "No LVM or LVM2 structure"

Tags: lvm, data-recovery

Here is the story, a little complicated. long time ago, i installed the a Linux system with only one LVM volume group which had only one physical volume(let's call it *disk A*), then i got a raid card(lsi 1064e controller), and built a raid1 array with two disks. naturally i decided to migrate my system (and the data) to the new raid array, i did that with command *pvmove*. everything looked fine, and i removed the *disk A* from the volume group(using *pvremove*) and used it for another box.

about several months ago, i got one new disk, and then i decided to build an ime raid array with three disks instead of raid1. so i got *disk A* back, and used *pvmove* to copy every thing in origin raid 1 array into *disk A*. after i finished the work, i used *pvmove* again, to copy things back to new ime raid. (after i recovered the volume group, i confirmed that i did running *vgreduce* at that time). but i didn't detached *disk A* from the box for some reason.

and today i repartitioned the *disk A* and removed it from the box again for something else. after i reset the box, **the grub can not find the volume group!!!!**. then i tried gentoo systemrescuecd, pvs printed nothing at all, and testdisk said "No LVM or LVM2 structure". obviously something like LVM metadata of the volume group in *disk A* had been lost.

now i'm running testdisk for a while, and waiting, i have to say i'm a little worried about my data, and i really think i need some advise about recovering the LVM metadata or just the data.

So now my question is why *pvs* can not give information? i mean i just repartitioned and removed one disk which was not in the volume group. if that caused my trouble, does it mean there is a bug in lvm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So now my question is why pvs can not give information?

Due to it's become absent, isn't it — {

> today i repartitioned the disk A

} — ?

LVM archives every operation in /etc/lvm/archive, bit if it's not accessible it's kinda useless now. Though there's a chance it could be found just by block-by-block text grepping.

Anyways, `testdisk` still has chances for you.